# Adding HTTPS capability to WAMPSERVER 2

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, openssl

I have WampServer 2 installed on my WinXP Pro SP3 box, Apache 2.2.11 with ssl module enabled, which runs the comnpanies intranet website.

http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html gives some pointers of generating a self signed certificate. 
But I encounter a error while running through the example

> ```
> openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
> ```

where openssl.exe is located under C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin

The error code that gets generated is

> 4828:error:02001015:system
>   library:fopen:Is a
>   directory:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:
>   126:fopen('d:/test/openssl098kvc6/openssl.cnf','rb')
>   4828:error:2006D002:BIO
>   routines:BIO_new_file:system
>   lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c :131:
>   4828:error:0E078002:configuration file
>   routines:DEF_LOAD:system
>   lib:.\crypto\con f\conf_def.c:199:

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Just an FYI - WampServer 2 (along with many of the other one-click stack installers) is meant to be used only as a development environment only. The developers of these packages configure things as to not get in the way of site development. As such, security is not great. If this is for limited internal use only, you're probably okay as long as you trust your users, but I'd never think of using it in production for a public-facing website.

Comment: @ErikA Intranet app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Windows person, so I can't give specific advice about WampServer or be confident that I'm interpreting your error message correctly, but it looks like it's complaining about not having a config file for openssl. You might want to try specifying it explicitly:

```
openssl genrsa -config <path to your openssl.cnf> -out server.key
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, it appears that openssl.exe is broken in some of the WampServer 2.0 releases.  (Just running openssl.exe without any options will trigger the similar errors)

I downloaded and installed the GNUWin port of OpenSSL from Sourceforge...
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm

And created my server key using this version of openssl.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the full version of openssl on your computer and creating the certificate through that.  Chances are you are missing some dependencies/etc.  Shining Light Productions has a compiled and installable version of openssl for windows.